# Python looping error checks

Tags: python, loops

my program takes a mathematical input and checks it for errors before proceeding, here is the part of the code I need help with:

```
expression= introduction()#just asks user to input a math expression    
operators= set("*/+-")
numbers= set("0123456789")
for i in expression:
    while i not in numbers and i not in operators:
        print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
        expression= introduction()
```

Now I have set up an error loop but the problem I am having is that I don't know what to update the loop with in this scenario. Anyone?

I need something simple. I need something close to the code that is posted in this OP. Something like:

```
expression= introduction()#just asks user to input a math expression    
operators= set("*/+-")
numbers= set("0123456789")
while True:
    for i in expression:
        if i not in numbers and i not in operators:
            print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
            expression= introduction()
    else:
        break
```

Note that this code doesn't work either. It loops for every single mistake that the user inputs for "expression".

Things such as what is below are too advanced and I cannot use them:

```
valid = operators | numbers
while True:
    expression = introduction()
    if set(expression) - valid:
        print 'not a valid expression, try again'
    else: 
        break
```

---

```
import string

expression = introduction()    
operators = {'*', '/', '+', '-'}
numbers = set(string.digits)
while any(char not in numbers and char not in operators for char in expression):
    print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
    expression = introduction()
```

Comment: Why can't you use something like `if not all(c in operators|numbers for c in expression)`?

Comment: I cant use the "all" part of it and cant use the separator either... @nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close in your 2nd code. You would need to do some changes, and your code should be like this: -

```
expression = ""
operators= set("*/+-")
numbers= set("0123456789")
while True:
    expression= introduction()  # You should read the next expression here
    for i in expression:
        if i not in numbers and i not in operators:
            print("Please enter valid inputs, please try again.")
            break # You should have a break here
    else:
        break

print expression  # Print if valid
```

- If the expression is not valid, it will only break out of `for loop`
  and continue the `while` loop.
- And, if the expression is valid, it will execute the `else block` of your `for-loop` and
  break out of the while loop.
- To use your `expression` outside your while loop, you would need to declare it outside the while loop.

Comment: @will it output expression regardless of if the loop runs or not?

Comment: You can print your `expression` in your `else block`. It will only print it, when the expression is valid.

Comment: can you join me in chat for just a couple of minutes

Comment: Sure. Wait. I'll post the chat room link

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `all()` or `any()`, you could test the length of the list which contains the errors:

```
if [c for c in expression if c not in operators|numbers]:
    # error
```

Without the `|` operator:

```
if [c for c in expression if c not in operators and c not in numbers]:
    # error
```

Comment: ,again, i cannot use the separator

Comment: @user1716168: if you can use a list, just replace `not in operators|numbers` by `c not in operators and c not in numbers`